# Wikitude sdk texture is not rendering in android using OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview, wikitude

This is the code I'm using to render a Bitmap in Wikitude SDK class ArchitectView

```
// clear Screen and Depth Buffer, we have set the clear color as black.
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
 int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "vPosition");

 // Enable generic vertex attribute array
 GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

 // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
 GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3,
                              GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                              0, vertexBuffer);

 // Get handle to texture coordinates location
 int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "a_texCoord" );

 // Enable generic vertex attribute array
 GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );

 // Prepare the texturecoordinates
 GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false, 
            0, uvBuffer);

 // Get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "uMVPMatrix");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, m, 0);

    // Get handle to textures locations
    int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "s_texture" );

    // Set the sampler texture unit to 0, where we have saved the texture.
    GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, 0);

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);
```

And this is how image being setup:

```
 public void SetupImage(Bitmap bmp)
 {
  // Create our UV coordinates.
  uvs = new float[] {
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,   
    1.0f, 0.0f   
     };

  // The texture buffer
  ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(uvs.length * 4);
  bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
  uvBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
  uvBuffer.put(uvs);
  uvBuffer.position(0);

  // Generate Textures, if more needed, alter these numbers.
  int[] texturenames = new int[1];
  GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texturenames, 0);



  // Bind texture to texturename
  GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
  GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[0]);

  // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);

        // We are done using the bitmap so we should recycle it.
  bmp.recycle();

 }
```

The problem is I can't render texture inside ArchitectView, but rendering it without any issues on default android's GLSurfaceView.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to write any OpenGL code inside the ArchitectView. If you need some custom drawing, please write a plugin for the Wikitude SDK and use the startRender/endRender method to draw your OpenGL content (Only these two methods guarantee a valid OpenGL context bound).